# Need help building a regex to accept two forms of strings

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I am looking to build a regular expression to parse a string, which can be of one of the following two forms: -

> Part 1 (Part 2 - Part 3)

or

> Part 1 (Part 2)

The following regular expression matches first string and captures all three parts

```
(.*)\((.*)(?:-)(.*)\)
```

But I am unable to improvise it so that it could match both strings. I want one regex to match both strings. Not sure if it is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(.*)\((.*?)(?:-(.*))?\)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldvIfZ/1)

**Details**

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:-(.*))?` - an optional group matching a `-` and then capturing into Group 3 any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char.

If there can be no other parentheses than those shown in the string, you may optimize the pattern to [`^([^()]*)\(([^()-]*)(?:-([^()]*))?\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ldvIfZ/2).

Comment: Thank you! Strings are unlikely to contain parentheses other than mentioned, but I've no control over them; so I'll stick to first form. I'll be processing about 200-300 strings at a time.